# Sourcing local .bashrc .vimrc without copy to remote machine

Tags: ssh, bashrc

Does anyone have an idea or hack on how to source my local dotfiles (I will probably need more of them so this solution should work with many files) on remote machines without scp them to remote machine?

Is something like scp .bashrc to /tmp folder on remote machine and then exporting BASHRC env variable the best solution?

I need this because of our company policy and fast cloud servers deployment and redeployment and I don't want to touch .bashrc files on remote machine so my colleges are able to use their default env which doesn't suit me.

Answer (score 0):

You can ssh to the remote machine upon which you can execute your local script on the remote machine.

```
ssh <remote machine ip> "/bin/sh -s" <  local_script_file
```